# Debug executable launched from a script using gdb

Tags: python, gdb

I have a python script (sample.py) which launches an executable file (a.out, an elf executable created from a C file using -g flag) using `subprocess.Popen` method. I want to use gdb for a.out. How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to debug Python script using debug build of your Python interpreter. There is a description of how to do it - [Low-level Python debugging with GDB](http://grapsus.net/blog/post/Low-level-Python-debugging-with-GDB).

When debugging, you can call gdb command `set follow-fork-mode child` before `subprocess.Popen` method executed. Gdb should now debug new process (a.out) after a fork instead of parent process (Python interpreter).

Answer (score 0):

does

```
cmd = ["gdb","a.out"]
Popen(cmd)
```

not work?

Comment: No. I get this error: (gdb) Hangup detected on fd 0
error detected on stdin